# Finding indexes with nested array object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, nested, use-state

Here I have this `useState` object, which is an array of objects. In each object, there is an array of objects. I'm trying to update the value of an object in the second array of objects. I generally have the logic worked out, but I need to know the index of the main object. I don't know how to grab it from where I am.

This is the function I'm planning to use to update the object. This function is being passed into another component for the `value` and `idx`. The component I pass this function to does not have the ability to access this `useState` directly. How can I find the index of `restaurant`?

Edit: added useState structure

```html
 const [restaurant, setRestaurant] = useState([])
 
 const updateMenuItem =(value, idx) => {
        
        var index = restaurants[i].restMenu.findIndex(x => x.idx === idx)
        let rest = restaurant[i]
        let item = restMenu[index]
        let new = rest.item
        new.menuItem = value
        
        setRestaurants([...restaurants.slice(0, i), ...restaurants.slice(i)])


    }
```

Here is the structure of my useState.

```html
restName: "name",
restCuisine: "cuisine",
restMenu: [
  { item: "item name",
    description: "some description",
    idx: id,
    ingres: [
      { item: "item name",
        idIngre: id }

    ]},
    
],
restMenuNum: "some number",
restId: id
```

[visulization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs8GE.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem fully. Are you trying to check if the menu of a restaurant has a specific item? Would `restaurants.findIndex(({restMenu}) => restMenu.findIndex(x => x.idx === idx) !== -1)` work?

Comment: @Calvin I'm updating a menu item. Like changing the name of it. Also... I did not realize I could do that...

Comment: @zelda3469 Why would you need to find the index though? Why can't you do just `find` ?

Comment: @Baruch Because I need to update the item value in the correct menu, in the correct restaurant. I have to know which restaurant value I'm editing. Not just the menu item.

Comment: @zelda3469 You can still use find? `const menuItem = restaurants.find(({ restMenu }) => restMenu.find((menu) => menu.idx === idx))`. Not only this is faster, it will return the item already.

Comment: @Baruch I see how finding it will work. I am still not understanding how this will work when I got to  add the item to the state. Do I just do `menuItem.item = value` at this point?